# regex to find LastnameFirstname with no space between in Python

Tags: python, regex

i currently have several names that look like this

```
SmithJohn
smithJohn
O'BrienPeter
```

both of these have no spaces, but have a capital letter in between.

is there a regex to match these types of names (but won't match names like `Smith`, `John`, `Smith John` or `Smith.John`)? furthermore, how could i split up the last name and first name into two different variables?

thanks

Comment: [`([A-Za-z']+)([A-Z][A-Za-z']+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ceR74N/1)

Comment: Can you show some examples where what you have tried does not work correctly?

Comment: Names are *so much more diverse than you think* that no regex in the world will ever do the right thing.

Comment: ...and yes, that means that you should give up and say "it cannot be done", because anything you try will be wrong for a relevant part of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a string with a capital letter in the middle and lowercase letters around it, this should work okay: `[a-z][A-Z]` (make sure you use `re.search` and not `match`). It handles "O'BrienPeter" fine, but might match names like "McCutchon" when it shouldn't. It's impossible to come up with a regex, or any program really, that does that you want for all names (see [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)).

Answer (score 0):

As Brian points out, there's a question you need to ask yourself here: What guarantees do you have about the strings you will be processing?

Do you know without a doubt that the only capitals will be the beginnings of the names? Or could something like "McCutchonBrian", or in my case "Mallegol-HansenPhilip" have found its way in there as well?

In the greater context of software in general, you need to consider the assumptions you are going in with. Otherwise you're going to be solving a problem, that is in fact not the problem you have.